# JPQL Like Case Insensitive

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I want to search data in User table by name case insensitive.

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  @Query("select u from User u where lower(u.name) like %lower(?1)%")
  public List<User> findByNameFree(String name);

}
```

I got an error: *unexpected token: %*. Where should I place '%'?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You can use the concat operator:

```
@Query("select u from User u where lower(u.name) like lower(concat('%', ?1,'%'))")
public List<User> findByNameFree(String name);
```

or with a named parameter:

```
@Query("select u from User u where lower(u.name) like lower(concat('%', :nameToFind,'%'))")
public List<User> findByNameFree(@Param("nameToFind") String name);
```

(Tested with Spring Boot 1.4.3)

Comment: Good approach. Thank you!

Comment: Note that this might change your query plan and bypass a SQL index, slowing down queries, especially with lots of users in the table. This is because it has to apply the lower() to all the values in the DB on every call.

Comment: @Max Thanks for that observation, did not think of that. According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12855/database-case-insensitive-index there are ways to avoid it, but it very much seems to depend on what db you are using.

Comment: when given null, boom baby!

Comment: it fails when nameToFind is null. any solution?

Comment: @MalinduSandaruwan that's because you need to specify what you want to happen when nameToFind is null. If you want to NOT filter by name, then the entire clause `lower(u.name) like lower(...)` must be omitted from the string. If you have multiple clauses, you will have to omit and `and` or replace the omitted part with a `1=1`. And so on.

Answer (score 41):

If that is only what you want and you are using Spring Data JPA you don't need to write a query.

```
List<User> findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(String name);
```

Else you need to wrap the `name` attribute with `%` before you pass it to the method (putting those directly in the query will simply not work). Or don't use a query but use a specification or the Criteria API to create the query.

Comment: I want to find solution for general problem that use query.

Comment: doesnt work... the value is not put to lowercase

Answer (score 17):

I am using Spring Boot 2.1.6, You can define query methods using Containing, Contains, and IsContaining as below:

```
List<User> findByNameContaining(String name);
List<User> findByNameContains(String name);
List<User> findByNameIsContaining(String name);
```

Case Insensitivity:

```
List<User> findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(String name);
```

OR you can also define as below as well:

```
@Query("select u from User u where lower(u.name) like lower(concat('%', :name,'%'))")
public List<User> findByName(@Param("name") String name);
```

The @Param annotation is important here because we're using a named parameter.

Comment: Does the concat result in `%name%` being the search term? What do the % do?

Answer (score 3):

Without using concat and using TypedQuery:

```
  TypedQuery<Baptism> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT d FROM " + Baptism.class.getSimpleName()
                            + " d JOIN d.person p WHERE UPPER(p.lastName) LIKE UPPER(:ln)", Baptism.class);
                    query.setParameter("ln", "%" + ln + "%");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring boot naming convention strategy to achieve with naming pattern like: findBy`YourFieldCamelCase`LikeIgnoreCase

`example: findByUserNameLikeIgnoreCase(userName: String): List<UserEntity>`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `wildcard matching`.

for example, i want to search name like `haha`,

```
@Query("select u from User u where lower(u.name) like :u_name")
public List<User> findByNameFree(@Param("u_name") String name);
List<User> users = userDao.findByNameFree("%haha");
```

Comment: @Query("select u from User u where lower(u.name) like lower(:u_name)")