# JPQL query not working for case insensitive parameters

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jpql, case-insensitive

I am trying to write a JPQL query for searching data based on String. when i am trying to search data with 'C' it works fine, but its not working for 'c', below is the query. for example: below query is working for Cat, College, Collapse, but not working for cat, college, collapse. any help is appreciate.

```
@Query("select ca.company_01 from CompanyAddress_02 ca WHERE ca.statusActiveSwitch = 'Y' AND ca.country.region.regionCode = :regionCode")
    Page<Company_01> findAllCompany_01Region(@Param("regionCode") String regionCode,  Pageable pageRequest);
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178520/jpql-like-case-insensitive

Comment: @ScaryWombat Not an exact duplicate of that one, but nice catch, I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to just lowercase both sides of the region code when comparing in your JPQL query:

```
@Query("SELECT ca.company_01 FROM CompanyAddress_02 ca WHERE ca.statusActiveSwitch = 'Y' AND LOWER(ca.country.region.regionCode) = LOWER(:regionCode)")
Page<Company_01> findAllCompany_01Region(@Param("regionCode") String regionCode,  Pageable pageRequest);
```

Note that if you don't really have any use for the case in your region code, then consider just storing it all in a one case, e.g. lowercase, and then ensure that what you pass to your backend is also always the same case.  This avoids calling `LOWER()`, which renders the `WHERE` clause non sargable (i.e. it cannot use an index).