# Spring Boot - JPA Repository @Query for mismatching entity field types

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, criteriaquery

How can I compare two entity fields with different data types in a @Query-statement?

I read about critera queries and know that there are functions that can modify parameters before they are used in the sql-statement, e.g. upper() or lower() like demonstrated here [JPQL Like Case Insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178520/jpql-like-case-insensitive) but I couldn´t find a criteria query suitable for my problem.

Do you know anything like the lower() or upper() functions which can solve my problem or can give me an idea what else I could try? Thanks in advance.

**First Entity**

```
@Data
@Entity
public class MerchantWhitelist implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String pspId;
    // ...

}
```

**Second Entity**

```
@Entity
public class MerchantConfiguration implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private Long uuid;
    // ...

}
```

**Repository**

```
@Query("select c from MerchantConfiguration c, MerchantWhitelist m where c.uuid = m.pspId)
    List<MerchantConfiguration> getData();
}
```

Comment: What is the datatype for `uuid` in database ?

Comment: Both parameters, uuid and pspID are varchar(11).

Comment: You can use `CAST (c.uuid AS string) = m.pspId` but don't understand how you are mapping Long into database for `uuid`