# How can I ignore case sensitivity in the query in JPA?

Tags: postgresql, jpa

I have a small question. I have the following query that should filter by externalId or carName. The query also works but the query is case sensitive. But the filter should ignore upper and lower case.

```
@Query("SELECT d FROM CarLocationEntityView d WHERE d.externalId LIKE %:carNameAndExternalId% OR d.carName LIKE %:carNameAndExternalId% ")
   List<CarLocationEntityView> findByCarNameAndExternalId(String carNameAndExternalId);
```

I am working with JPA and a Postgres Sql database.

**FIRST TRY:**

```
@Query("SELECT d FROM CarLocationEntityView d WHERE d.externalId LIKE %:carNameAndExternalId% OR d.carName LIKE '%:carNameAndExternalId% COLLATE latin1_general_cs' ")
   List<CarLocationEntityView> findByCarNameAndExternalId(String carNameAndExternalId);
```

Does not work

**SECOND TRY:**

```
@Query("SELECT d FROM CarLocationEntityView d WHERE d.externalId LIKE %:carNameAndExternalId% OR d.carName LIKE low(%:carNameAndExternalId% )")
   List<CarLocationEntityView> findByCarNameAndExternalId(String carNameAndExternalId);
```

Does not work either

**THIRD TRY:**

```
@Query("SELECT d FROM CarLocationEntityView d WHERE d.externalId LIKE %:carNameAndExternalId% OR d.carName ILIKE %:carNameAndExternalId% ")
   List<CarLocationEntityView> findByCarNameAndExternalId(String carNameAndExternalId);
```

Does not work either

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41988897/496099

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPQL 2.1 added FUNCTION to call DB specific operations, but ILIKE wouldn't work in it. There are some JPA provider specific options, but generally I see projects just use lower on strings, similar to your second try, but on both strings for case insensitive comparisons. Something like:

```
"SELECT d FROM CarLocationEntityView d WHERE d.externalId LIKE %:carNameAndExternalId% OR lower(d.carName) LIKE lower(concat('%', :carNameAndExternalId,'%') )"
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply. But this has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

try `ILIKE` instead of `LIKE`, should work, see the documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE):

> The key word ILIKE can be used instead of LIKE to make the match
> case-insensitive according to the active locale. This is not in the
> SQL standard but is a PostgreSQL extension.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it seems that JPA does not accept ILIKE.